# Can geometric point counting detect prime powers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let's call a polynomial $P(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ realizable if there exists some polynomial-count scheme $X$ over $\mathbb Z$ that satisfies $|X(\mathbb F_q)|=P(q)$, for all prime powers $q$.

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer that is not a prime power. Can one always find a realizable polynomial that satisfies $P(n)<0$?

Comment: Do you know of such a polynomial for say, $n=6$?

Comment: @dhy There is a combinatorial construction in D. Glynn, "Rings of geometries II" J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 49 (1988), no. 1, 26-66. The author essentially shows that a certain polynomial of degree 14 gives a negative value at 6, but can be interpreted as counting the points of some variety. This variety is defined combinatorially, in a way that would allow you to define its points over a finite projective plane. The author uses this to prove the nonexistence of finite planes of order 6. Of course, no such example is known for $n>6$.

Comment: I found a more modern reference that has essentially the same example, written in geometric language. See table 1 in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.16014